# In this low side switching schematic does the 10k resistor play any role?

Tags: mosfet, switches, low-side

[image]

I've been given this schematic to review it (I'm working on a formula student team.) It is used for cutting off the power to a motor through a N-mosfet (NCV8402A).  The 12V are being supplied through a battery.  The motor will be connected to the connector on the right.

I had a disagreement with the team member that made the board about the use of the R6 resistor. He told me that he used that resistor as a "pull up" to avoid the situation of the pin number 2 floating when the transistor switch opens. I told him that I don't agree because you can't define a pull up resistor without having a ground at your circuit and that the main reason for using a low side switch is for the ground pin to actually "float" because it is an open circuit.  I also told him that in normal operation 1.2mA of current will flow through the R6 for no reason.

Who is right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're  both forgetting that there's a very low resistance path through the motor. If the MOSFET is switched off pin 2 (and the tab) will be pulled high by the motor.

[image]

*Figure 1. The 10k resistor will have negligible affect compared to the low resistance of the motor.*

R6 is not required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Can you be a bit more specific about the use of the term "Pulled high"? When the switch opens the motor is not connected to the supply ground, no current will flow through it's resistance so no voltage drop right? With my knowledge i can't understand how pin 2 has 12 Volts.
Finally if that wasn't a motor but something else, would it then make sense to use the R6 or it is useless at all scenarios?

Comment: Pin 1 has 12V. No current via load, so ohm's law says no voltage drop over load so both load pins have equal voltage. Therefore pins 1 and 2 have same voltage, 12V. R6 could be useful if the load was capasitive, like a piezo speaker and it should be much lower in resistance. But with motors, lamps and resistors, R6 is useless. R4 being  1k can limit how fast the FET turns on and off so slowly controlled FET may overheat. I don't recomnend PWM.

Comment: R6 could be used for testing if there is no load connected. That would be the only reason to install R6. Still, a testing jig would/could/should have a dummy motor.